# Can't see session when entering site

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I have problem with sessions in CodeIgniter.
When user log in to system I have this code:

```
$data_login = array(
    'id' => $user->id,
    'name' => $user->name,
    'email' => $user->email,
    'logged_in' => true
);
$this->session->set_userdata($data_login);
```

My sessions config:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

In general, everything works but when I do not log out and close the page tab, then I will visit the site again **$this->session->userdata('logged_in')** returns NULL. When I enter another subpage, everything returns to normal - recognizes the logged in user.

Where is problem? :/

@edit:

Here is my cookie config:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

@edit2:

I noticed that this happened on the new hosting.
Everything works on old hosting.

Comment: where's your session_start?

Comment: @treyBake no need to start session in Codeigniter.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra not used before^^ seems weird though, feel like you should init a session each time you use one (or use a lib function to init the session) - seems like it would be inefficient to handle session per session call ..

Comment: @treyBake there probably is a `session_start` being called when the framework is bootstrapped.

Comment: @treyBake yes CI having their own lib  to manage session and started session.

Comment: @web_newbie try to store session in DB

Comment: In CI the `session` library ("library"==="class" in CI talk) needs to be loaded before it can be used. Where are you loading `session`?

Comment: @DFriend, I load session in config/autoload.php

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your cookie configs.

Comment: @DFriend, done.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $data_login = array(
        'id' => $user->id,
        'name' => $user->name,
        'email' => $user->email
       );

   $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $data_login);
```

My sessions config :

```
   $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
   $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
   $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
   $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
   $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
   $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
   $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Don't forgot load session library

```
   $this->load->library('session');
```

Comment: The same problem :/ I think that is something with my new hosting - everything works on old hosting.